# change linetype when using dfmelt with breaks

Tags: r

To plot the time series of one month over multiple years I'm using the following code:

```
JAN<-subset(nDF, format.Date(DATE, "%m")=="01")
dfmelt<-melt(JAN,id.vars="DATE")
breaks <- unique(as.Date(cut(dfmelt$DATE, "month")))
ba2 <- transform(dfmelt, year = as.integer(format(DATE, "%Y")))
p <- ggplot(ba2, aes(x=DATE,y=value,
                     col=variable)) +  labs(title='JANUARY')+
  geom_line(lwd=1.0,alpha=0.5) + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(year), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")+
 theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
p + scale_x_date(breaks = breaks, date_labels = "%b")

 head(JAN)
          DATE     MODEL         BC   OBSERVED
215 2001-01-01 1.2860092 1.52571356 1.55332905
216 2001-01-02 0.7906073 1.24322433 1.24701969
217 2001-01-03 0.3687850 0.11566294 0.11677768
218 2001-01-04 0.3539595 0.15826654 0.15906525
219 2001-01-05 0.2531596 0.18768851 0.18768533
220 2001-01-06 0.2311364 0.01537928 0.01516614
```

However since BC and Observed have almost same values, I would like to change linetype of MODEL and OBSERVED only . How do I achieve this as any change I do reflects in all three lines

Answer (score 0):

Add `linetype=` to your `aes`thetics. Perhaps:

```r
p <- ggplot(ba2, aes(x=DATE, y=value, color=variable, linetype=variable)) +
  labs(title='JANUARY') +
  geom_line(lwd=1.0, alpha=0.5) + 
  facet_grid(cols=vars(year), scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines"))
p
```

[image: ggplot with linetype]

---

Data

```r
ba2 <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(11323, 11324, 11325, 11326, 11327, 11328, 11323, 11324, 11325, 11326, 11327, 11328, 11323, 11324, 11325, 11326, 11327, 11328), class = "Date"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("MODEL", "BC", "OBSERVED"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.2860092, 0.7906073, 0.368785, 0.3539595, 0.2531596, 0.2311364, 1.52571356, 1.24322433, 0.11566294, 0.15826654, 0.18768851, 0.01537928, 1.55332905, 1.24701969,  0.11677768, 0.15906525, 0.18768533, 0.01516614), year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. however as far as my understanding goes we cannot customize alpha. like keeping different alpha for all 3?

Comment: Have you ever tried `aes(alpha=variable)`? (it can work). Regardless, I thought you were trying to customize linetype by the variable, when did customizing alpha become an issue, esp since you explicitly call `alpha=0.5`? You could (for instance) do `aes(alpha=variable)` and `scale_alpha_manual(values = c(BC=1, MODEL=0.5, OBSERVED=0.1))`

Comment: alpha =variable tried following your example. however its was too light. hence I asked you.  Thankyou for your suggestion. `scale_alpha_manual` works great.